# Wicket: Dynamically fill cells with custom content

Tags: java, listview, html-table, wicket, markup

I made a table using wicket ListViews to create the columns and the rows, code looks like this:

ErhebungMatrixPanel.java

```
public ErhebungMatrixPanel(String id) {
    super(id);
    this.add(matrixForm);
    matrixForm.add(new ListView<Zustaendigkeit>("columns", zustaendigkeiten){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Zustaendigkeit> item) {
            final int index = item.getIndex();
            item.add(new Label("zustLabel", zustaendigkeiten.get(index).getName().toString()));
        }
    });

    matrixForm.add(rows = new ListView<Erhebung>("rows", erhebungen){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Erhebung> item) {
            final IModel<Boolean> checked = Model.of(Boolean.FALSE);
            final int index = item.getIndex();
            item.add(new Label("erhebungLabel", erhebungen.get(index).getName()));

            item.add(new AjaxCheckBox("check", checked) {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    //TODO
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In this table I want to put an AjaxCheckBox into every cell, to create something like an **authorization matrix** now the problem is, since the length of the List *zustaendigkeiten* most likely grow larger some time, that I can't insert a static amount of CheckBoxes. Right now only one column of the table is covered with CheckBoxes. The responding .html file looks like this:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <form wicket:id="matrixForm">
        <table class="matrix">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headers">
                    <th></th>
                    <span wicket:id="columns">
                        <th wicket:id="zustLabel"></th>
                    </span>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr wicket:id="rows">
                    <th wicket:id="erhebungLabel"></th>
                    <td><input wicket:id="check" type="checkbox" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</wicket:panel>
```

Something like this:

```
<tbody>
<tr wicket:id="rows">
    <th wicket:id="erhebungLabel"></th>
    <td><input wicket:id="check" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input wicket:id="check" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input wicket:id="check" type="checkbox" /></td>                
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Would obviously not work because 1. It should be dynamical, but I gues JS could help out there, 2. Wicket would throw a MarkUp error.

Is there any newCellItem alike method I could use like there is in a DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you need?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th wicket:id="headerList"><span wicket:id="name"></span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr wicket:id="rowList">
            <td wicket:id="name"></td>
            <td wicket:id="cellList">
                <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="checkbox"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Java:

```
add(new ListView<User>("headerList", new PropertyModel<>(this, "users")) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> listItem) {
        listItem.add(new Label("name", new PropertyModel(listItem.getModelObject(), "name")));
    }
});

add(new ListView<String>("rowList", new PropertyModel<>(this, "roles")) {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> listItem) {
        final String role = listItem.getModelObject();

        listItem.add(new Label("name", role));

        listItem.add(new ListView<User>("cellList", new PropertyModel<>(TestPage.this, "users")) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> listItem) {
                final User user = listItem.getModelObject();

                listItem.add(new AjaxCheckBox("checkbox", new IModel<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean getObject() {
                        return user.getRoles().contains(role);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setObject(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        if (aBoolean) {
                            user.getRoles().add(role);
                        } else {
                            user.getRoles().remove(role);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void detach() {

                    }
                }) {

                    @Override
                    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```